# Calendar and categories

Tags: solspace-calendar, low-seg2cat

i'm using exp:calendar:events to show all events that belong to certain dates and categories. Now i have 2 URL segments {segment_2} and {segment_3} that show category ids for example {segment_2} is category 6 and {segment_3} is category 17

if i have category="{segment_2}|{segment_3}" i get entries that belong either to one category or another.

The same happens if i put category="6|17" avoiding segments

What i really want is to get the results for category 6 AND category 17 (entries that belong to both these categories)

is that possible in a straightforward way? if not can it be used in combination with Low Seg2Cat or some other tool?

Thanks

- EE 3.4.7 and Calendar (ver 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *stuartmcd69* says, what you need to do is use the `&` character instead of `|`. However, the current version of Calendar (2.2.3) has a bug where this does NOT work. We're close to releasing a 2.3.0 version that will include a bug fix for this though.

If you need a patch now, just [create a support ticket here](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/create-ticket/calendar) :)

Comment: Thank you for the speed in your response ... i realised that it is a bug as it does not work after many tries

Comment: I confirm that it is a bug as category="x&y" does not produce the expected results

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, using the pipe character will return results if entries belong to either category id. To return those that belong to both then use the `&` symbol instead of the `|` character.

[Link to the docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#category) read it :)